# Cannot replace html text field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple to do list project. When the user inputs an item, it stores the data in the data structure which contains three arrays for the three different types of activity. I keep receiving an error message "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" against this line: newHtml = html.replace('%activity%', obj.activity); when trying to replace the html placeholder text with the text that the user inputs when adding a new item to the UI.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
addListItem: function(obj, type) {
  var html, newHtml;

  //1. create HTML string with placeholder text

  if (type === 'health') {

    html = '<div class="item row" id="health-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><p class="item_percentage">5%</p><button class="delete_btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';

  } else if (type === 'work') {

    html = '<div class="item row" id="work-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><p class="item_percentage">5%</p><button class="delete_btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';

  } else if (type === 'leisure') {

    html = '<div class="item row" id="leisure-%id%"><p class="item_description">%activity%</p><p class="item_start">%start%</p><p class="until">until</p><p class="item_end">%end%</p><p class="item_percentage">5%</p><button class="delete_btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div>';

  }

  // 2. replace placeholder with some actual text 
  newHtml = html.replace('%activity%', obj.activity);
  newHtml = newHtml.replace('%id%', obj.id);
  newHtml = newHtml.replace('%start%', obj.startTime);
  newHtml = newHtml.replace('%end%', obj.endTime);


  // 3. insert HTML into the DOM
  document.querySelector(DOMstrings.list).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);

},
```

The activity text is originally taken from this public method:

```
return {
  getInput: function() {
    return {
      type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,
      activity: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputActivity).value,
      startTime: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputStart).value,
      endTime: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputEnd).value
    };
  },
```

I have tried to debug the code using breakpoints and it keeps saying 'type is undefined' against the if/else statements.

Here's how I am calling the addListItem function (number 3):

```
// 1. get the field input data 
        var usersInput = UICtrl.getInput();

        // 2. add item to the activity controller arrays
        newItem = activityCtrl.addItem(usersInput.type, usersInput.activity, usersInput.startTime, usersInput.endTime);

        // 3. add the new item(s) to the UI (into the correct position depending on what the time is)
        UICtrl.addListItem(newItem);
```

Comment: `type` is most likely undefined and is not hitting any of the conditions which will make `html` also undefined which is why it's failing. Check to see what type is at the start of `addListItem` and debug from there.

Comment: Most probably `type` doesn't hit any of the `if else` conditions

Comment: you should show how you are calling `addListItem`

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone. You are right that 'type' is undefined but I don't understand why? The type is taken from what the user selects on the UI and is saved into three different arrays which are here: // data structure
var data = {
    allItems: {
        health: [],
        work: [],
        leisure: []
    }
};

Comment: `3. addListItem(newItem)` ... well, type is `undefined` in this case - because you haven't given a second argument